# Is it possible to securely encrypt / decrypt strings on the client side, using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption

I have a need to communicate with a third party service via an encrypted cookie.

For example, my application needs to:

- create a message, encrypt it using a public key, and then set it to a cookie.
- Then, the external service needs to decrypt the message with the private key, act upon it, then re-encrypt the message with the public key, and add it back to the cookie.
- Then, finally, my site needs to decrypt the message using the private key and act upon it, as well.

I know this can all be done securely on the server-side.

My question is, can this be done securely on the client side via javascript? Isn't it impossible, because I would need to expose the key(s) to the browser in some way?

Comment: You're talking about "the" singular private key, but both the client and the server can each have their own pair of public and private keys. Each client can know the server's public key, and use that to encrypt and send its private key to the server.

Comment: True. In this case, however, I can't supply a key to the third party - they supply the keys to me.

Comment: Is this a system you are designing or is it an existing system that you have to communicate with?  Do you have control over the back-end and the way it behaves?

Comment: The third party service is a system I communicate with (not one that I have any control over). They issue pub/priv keys

Comment: This is for data to be stored / persisted in a cookie across many pageloads. Think of it as a "shared shopping cart" that two completely separate applications need access to, and need to be able to edit.

Comment: @johnnietheblack what do you need? confidentiality of original content or integrity? you just want to prevent original tempering or you want it to be encrypted too?

Comment: @afshin i need both. I can get both on the server-side...i just need to see if i can get both on the client side